# What is Plain FormSet

Tags: django-forms

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete

"On the other hand, if you are using a plain FormSet, it’s up to you to handle formset.deleted_forms, perhaps in your formset’s save() method, as there’s no general notion of what it means to delete a form."

Could you help me understand what is "plain FormSet".

Maybe BaseFormSet would be better?

I'm a newbie in Django.

Shall I create a new ticket about cleanup/optimization of documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain formset is a class returned by `formset_factory`.

There is also `modelformset_factory`, which returns model formsets.

When you call [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) on a model formset, it will take care of deleting objects that you marked to delete.

The docs are saying that plain (non-model) formsets will not take care of deleting objects for you, so you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: Is it a bad wording in documentation? I mean you you wrote "plain formset" whereas the documentation mentioned "plain FormSet". In case of  formset_factory(MyArticleForm) we will get django.forms.formsets.MyArticleFormFormSet. Everything is rather vague. If your wording may be understood metaphorically, the documentation may not. As far as I can see there is no FormSet in the nagure at all. There are descendants of BaseFormSet. Should I think, create a new ticket and offer a better wording to the community?

Comment: I don't think changing `FormSet` to `BaseFormSet` would be an improvement. A model formset class is still a descendent of `BaseFormSet` (via `BaseModelFormSet`).

Comment: But do you agree that "plain FormSet" is not piece of excellent wording? I may think of a better offer and suggest it for the community to approve.

Comment: Personally, I think 'plain FormSet' is OK, unless I see a better suggestion.